# PyCharm Theano installation error

Tags: pycharm, theano

While trying to import theano in pycharm I'm getting this error. How can I resolve it?

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
C:\Python27\libs/python27.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How are you trying to import it?

Comment: I installed it from the PyCharm project interpreter. For the g++ dependencies I did as this link says http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html